# datastructure or implementation of buddy heap algo

Tags: data-structures

i want to know how buddy heap  algo works or what datastructure is being used in it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're thinking of [buddy memory allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation)? There's the link to the Wikipedia page. It does mention:

> Typically the buddy memory allocation
>   system is implemented with the use of
>   a binary tree to represent used or
>   unused split memory blocks.

If you have difficulty understanding the Wikipedia entry, can you perhaps update your question to state more specifically what part you're having problems with?